# Cancellative commutative monoid

Tags: monoid

In textbook which I am studying,

LEMMA 1 
A commutative monoid $S$ can be embedded in a group if and only if it admits cancellation by all elements:
$ac=bc$ implies $a=b,$ for all $a,b,c \in S.$

I think reverse of this lemma 1 is only right when $S$ is a finite set.

How do you think about it?

Comment: Do you have an infinite counterexample?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse"? The Lemma is an "if and only if" statement, not merely an implication. And it holds regardless of whether $S$ is finite or infinite.

Comment: If $S$ is finite and cancellative, then in fact, it must actually already be an abelian group.

Comment: It’s pretty easy to define the abelian group - the same way we define $\mathbb Z$ from $\mathbb N.$

Comment: The right-to-left direction of this wouldn't be true without the assumption that $S$ is commutative. Is that what you missed?

Comment: Thank you very much for many helpful comments. I misunderstood what 'be embedded in' is. <br/> Tomas Andrews comments it's pretty easy. but I think it's not as easy as defining Z from N because we cannot define '-x' freely. <br/> We need several steps for embedding like equivalence class and new symbol. <br/> Do I misunderstand one more?